# Flutter - Street view package no longer working over last couple of days

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-street-view

I have been developing a new Flutter app that is using the Flutter 'Google Street View' package, see https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_street_view/versions/1.0.2

A couple of days ago the street view display just stopped working.  The stack trace is shown below. Any suggestions?

```
/DynamiteModule(22111): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 7
I/SnapshotHandler(22111): Unable to retrieve flag snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.eis.lejog.lejog, using defaults.
```

By co-incidence,  I am using Intellij and I do remember thee being an Android update around about the same time

Answer (score 0):

Its working again now.  Must have been a service provision issue with Google

Answer (score 0):

Use this version the issue is resolved now

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_street_view/versions/2.2.8